# How to fit an image into a larger image? Python, pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I want to fit into another bigger image, so the smaller image is as big as possible. Is there a possible way to do that? It's like resizing without deforming the ratio.

I have tried this code:

```
image = Image.open(input_path)

x, y = image.size

offset_x = math.floor((512 - x) / 2)
offset_y = math.ceil((512 - y) / 2)

output_image = Image.new(image.mode, (512, 512), (255, 255, 255, 0))
output_image.paste(image, (offset_x, offset_y))


output_image.save(output_path)
```

but it doesn't really work. (note that 512 and 512 are the result sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is the ImageOps.pad() function. I didn't know it existed, so yeah.